# Sed command to clean a csv is not working

Tags: bash, csv, hadoop, sed

I have a CSV file that I would like to:

```
Replace all &amp; instances with &
Remove the first (header) line
Change all semicolons to $$$
Change all "$$$" instances into ";"
Remove all " characters
```

The sed command to do it looks like this:

```
 sed 's/\&amp;/\&/g' BX-Book-Ratings:| sed -e '1d' |sed 's/;/$$$/g' | sed 's/"$$$"/";"/g' | sed 's/"//g' > corrected_rating
```

But it doesn't work when I put it in the terminal of the ClouderaVM...

It gives me the error: `sed: can't read BX-Book-Ratings:: No such file or directory`

I put a copy of BX-Book-Ratings.csv on the desktop and the root folder and I tried putting the direct location in the sed command. What am I doing wrong?

I am getting the error: `line sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to`s'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use so many pipes? What about such approach:

```
sed 's/\&amp\;/\&/g;1d;s/;/$$$/g;s/"$$$"/";"/g;s/"//g' BX-Book-Ratings.csv > corrected_rating
```

Or if you want to store the result to a variable do it like this:

```
var=$(sed 's/\&amp\;/\&/g;1d;s/;/$$$/g;s/"$$$"/";"/g;s/"//g' BX-Book-Ratings.csv)
```

Comment: I am really new to this I am not used to Bash scripts.

Comment: your command worked very well I just put  corrected_rating.csv at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If the filename is `BX-Book-Ratings.csv` then you need to use that instead of `BX-Book-Ratings:` in the command line. This is not a `sed` error, it's a problem from your shell.

Comment: Do i need to cd to the same folder as the file?

Comment: @MarkLang Or provide a full path to file, yes.

Comment: It still says sed: can't read BX-Book-Ratings.csv:: No such file or directory

Comment: @MarkLang include the full path to that csv file.